# Mysql auto insert a value after substraction

Tags: mysql

I am working on a car rental system. The table 'Hire' has fields like `hireDate`, `returnDate`, etc. I want to be able to calculate the rent and insert that value automatically into the database (same table).

I am wondering if I can subtract these two date fields, and the value which comes out of this can be multiplied by a certain number (say 300) and automatically added to another attribute called '`Rent_Due`'. The idea is to calculate the total rent due by getting the number of days and then multiplying that by a certain number. So for every Hire that is made, I just enter the hiring date and the return date, and the Rent Due attribute is automatically filled. Is this possible by any chance?

I dont know what more information I need to provide to seek help, kindly let me know if you might require an image of my ERD.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the difference you want to compute in in days, this should work.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (hireDate, returnDate, Rent_Due) VALUES
(StartDate. EndDate, DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)*300)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would steer clear of having calculated fields in the database, and try to keep it normalized.

You could, instead, use a view for the duration of hire and hence the price.

Example as follows:

```
create view hire_duration as (
  select hireId, hireDate, datediff(returnDate,hireDate) as duration
  from Hire
);
```

(This assumes you have a primary key called hireId in your Hire table)
You could easily modify the view to have cost of hire as well, by multiplying duration by some constant, and that would be OK if the cost never changes, but if it you want to have the flexibility of different hire rates you wound't want to hard-code a rate in your SQL.

Comment: Thank you @NickJ, will look into your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't required to create another field you can get your result be the following query.

```
select (datediff(hireDate, returnDate)*300) as rent,hireDate,returnDate from Hire;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for maybe something like this?

Before-Insert-Event:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER name_of_before_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON name_of_table
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     SET NEW.Rent_Due = DATEDIFF(NEW.returnDate, NEW.hireDate) * 300;
    END;
   $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Before-Update-Event:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER name_of_before_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON name_of_table
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     SET NEW.Rent_Due = DATEDIFF(NEW.returnDate, NEW.hireDate) * 300;
    END;
   $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The daily rate you can also outsource in a separate table:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER name_of_before_insert_event_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON name_of_table
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     SET NEW.Rent_Due = DATEDIFF(NEW.returnDate, NEW.hireDate) * (SELECT value FROM name_of_price_table LIMIT 1);
    END;
   $$
DELIMITER ;
```